# Allocating memory to a char* in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

When going through a C++ code I came across a line where the developer is trying to add a new cell to a `char**` variable. While doing so, following is the line of code he is using to allocate memory for the new cell.

```
*(plantValue + (plantCount-1)) = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * SAPPlantStr.length());
```

where `plantValue` is `char**` and `plantCount` is an integer.

Could someone please explain me the above line of code as I am unable to understand it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is equal to `p[i]`. In your specific case it means that `*(plantValue + (plantCount-1))` is equal to `plantValue[plantCount-1]`. Hopefully that should make it clearer for you.

Comment: Also, you should probably throw that code away if you use it to learn C++. "Proper" C++ would be to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for strings, and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for a dynamic "array".

Comment: Oh and there's probably a bug in the code you show, as the allocation doesn't include space for a terminating `'\0'` character.

Comment: Thank you for response. I have got my doubt clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `plantValue` in your code is a pointer to an array of pointers to raw C-style strings, i.e.:

```
               +----------+
plantValue --> |  char *  | --> String #1
(char **)      +----------+
               |  char *  | --> String #2
               +----------+
               |   ...    |
               +----------+
               |  char *  | --> String #N
               +----------+
```

So, that code is basically allocating a new C-style string using `malloc()`, and storing a pointer to it in a slot in the `char*` vector represented above.

In particular, `plantCount-1` is the index of the first available slot in the pre-allocated pointer array; `plantValue + (plantCount-1)` points to that slot, and with `*(plantValue + (plantCount-1)) = ...` you write the string pointer returned by `malloc()` in that slot.

Please note that the above code is more C than C++; for example, in C++ you would use `new[]` instead of `malloc()` for explicit dynamic memory allocations; but, even better, in C++ you should use standard **container classes** likes `std::vector`, and `std::string` instead of raw `char*` owning pointers. These C++ classes *automatically* manage their own memory, and simplify your code a lot.

**P.S.** Note also that C-style strings are NUL-terminated, so when you allocate memory for a new string with `malloc()`, you should consider also the terminating NUL when you compute the *total* length (in other words, you should have `SAPPlantStr.length() + 1` in your code).

Comment: Thank you for response. I have got my doubt clarified.

Answer (score 0):

plantValue[plantCount-1] contains a pointer to allocated memory with length of SAPPlantStr

Comment: And that's how he should have written it. The pointer dereferencing syntax is confusing.